# Can't add rocks from Rock Generator Addon

Tags: python, add-on

I successfully added the addon and enabled it:

[image: Add Mesh: Rock Generator added and enabled]

But I can't execute it, because it is grayed out:

[image: Add/Mesh/Rock Generator is disabled]

The blender console shows the following:

[image: debug console output]

Calling the function to add rocks via Python gives the following error, if this is of any help:

[image: execute add rocks]

Any ideas why this addon won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely, rock generator requires that you have an object selected. Try adding a cube, then it should be available.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me!! It's not that you need an object to be selected, it's that you need at least one object in your scene, or so it seems. I added a cube, deselected it, and now I am able to add a rock. The addon seems not to work without at least one object (mesh?) in your scene. I was using an empty scene when I was unable to execute the script via the Add/Mesh menu.

Comment: Yeah, strange requirement.